# GoogleAuthUtil.getToken() returns invalid token ("kid" is not found in the list of public keys and "exp" is Sun 18 January 1970)

Tags: android, oauth

An Android application uses the `getToken(Context context, Account account, String scope)` function from [GoogleAuthUtil](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil). The backend server has a number of situations where the token is not valid. In particular:

1. Tokens are signed with a key (kid) which is not a valid key for
   any of the published Google certificates on any of www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs, www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/certs, www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs
2. The "exp" parameter is pointing to Sun 18 January 1970.

It happens to real users, with real devices and with correct date set.

Does anyone know what's going wrong and how come that `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()` sometimes returns invalid token?